# How to convert a PyObject in Python C-extension to a string type?

Tags: python, python-c-extension

Just can't find the right function. Thanks for advice.

Comment: You've been asking a lot of questions about the Python C API recently. Have you tried looking at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/)?

Comment: I knew this function exists, but I couldn't find it easily in the documentation and had to resort to google, so I can see why the OP asked this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`PyObject_Str`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Str):

> `PyObject* PyObject_Str(PyObject *o)`
>
> > Return value: New reference.
>
> Compute a string representation of object `o`. Returns the string representation on success, `NULL` on failure. This is the equivalent of the Python expression `str(o)`. Called by the `str()` built-in function and by the `print` statement.